# How to create SMT in Kafka Connect for JSON message?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to setup a Kafka connector for sink to local file system with SMT to filter a few messages. Messages in Kafka topic are JSON type produced as follows:

```
curl -s https://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps | kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic meetups

{"venue":{"venue_name":"Online event","lon":179.1962,"lat":-8.521147,"venue_id":26906060},"visibility":"public","response":"yes","guests":0,"member":{"member_id":230381644,"photo":"https:\/\/secure.meetupstatic.com\/photos\/member\/4\/6\/9\/c\/thumb_268158076.jpeg","member_name":"Tharindu Gurusinghe"},"rsvp_id":1853832558,"mtime":1603346894745,"event":{"event_name":"IoT Data Architecture - Dave Glover","event_id":"273287718","time":1604487600000,"event_url":"https:\/\/www.meetup.com\/mssgug\/events\/273287718\/"},"group":{"group_topics":[{"urlkey":"web-development","topic_name":"Web Development"},{"urlkey":"microsoft-technology","topic_name":"Microsoft Technology"},{"urlkey":"microsoft-sharepoint-technology","topic_name":"Microsoft SharePoint Technology"},{"urlkey":"powershell","topic_name":"PowerShell"},{"urlkey":"microsoft-azure","topic_name":"Microsoft Azure"},{"urlkey":"microsft","topic_name":"Microsoft"},{"urlkey":"saas-software-as-a-service","topic_name":"SaaS (Software as a Service)"},{"urlkey":"iaas-infrastructure-as-a-service","topic_name":"IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service)"},{"urlkey":"technology","topic_name":"Technology"},{"urlkey":"azure","topic_name":"Azure"},{"urlkey":"dotnet","topic_name":".NET"},{"urlkey":"cloud-computing","topic_name":"Cloud Computing"},{"urlkey":"softwaredev","topic_name":"Software Development"},{"urlkey":"xamarin","topic_name":"Xamarin"}],"group_city":"Singapore","group_country":"sg","group_id":18429776,"group_name":"Azure, Office and Data Community (Singapore)","group_lon":103.85,"group_urlname":"mssgug","group_lat":1.3}}

{"venue":{"venue_name":"New York","lon":-74.005974,"lat":40.712776,"venue_id":26019022},"visibility":"public","response":"no","guests":0,"member":{"member_id":14283290,"photo":"https:\/\/secure.meetupstatic.com\/photos\/member\/5\/b\/c\/3\/thumb_264143491.jpeg","member_name":"karla johnson"},"rsvp_id":1853832556,"mtime":1603346894960,"event":{"event_name":"NY Deadlines: Register to Vote by Oct 9. Request an Absentee Ballot by Oct 27","event_id":"273649014","time":1603839480000,"event_url":"https:\/\/www.meetup.com\/NYC-Experience\/events\/273649014\/"},"group":{"group_topics":[{"urlkey":"cultural-activities","topic_name":"Cultural Activities"},{"urlkey":"performing-arts","topic_name":"Performing Arts"},{"urlkey":"museum","topic_name":"Museum"},{"urlkey":"arts","topic_name":"Arts & Entertainment"},{"urlkey":"fun-times","topic_name":"Fun Times"},{"urlkey":"music","topic_name":"Music"},{"urlkey":"film","topic_name":"Film"},{"urlkey":"philosophy","topic_name":"Philosophy"},{"urlkey":"socialnetwork","topic_name":"Social Networking"},{"urlkey":"diningout","topic_name":"Dining Out"},{"urlkey":"adventure","topic_name":"Adventure"},{"urlkey":"science","topic_name":"Science"},{"urlkey":"intellectual-discussion","topic_name":"Intellectual Discussion"},{"urlkey":"conversation","topic_name":"Conversation"},{"urlkey":"newintown","topic_name":"New In Town"}],"group_city":"New York","group_country":"us","group_id":6745272,"group_name":"\"The NYC Experience\"","group_lon":-74,"group_urlname":"NYC-Experience","group_state":"NY","group_lat":40.72}}
```

These are two sample messages produced to Kafka topic meetups. I have created a connector with the following configurations:

```
name=file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=/root/sink.test
topics=meetups
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

I'm able to see messages getting pushed to file /root/sink.test. Next thing I want to go filter messages based on "venue". I only want to push messages where "venue" = "New York". What is the exact configuration file to achieve this?

Comment: You can't use a field filtering SMT with StringConverter. The messages are only strings, not key-valued JSON in Kafka's view. I'd suggest you try ksql for that anyway

Comment: Otherwise, you could do `https://stream.meetup.com/2/rsvps | jq '<your filter>' | kafka-console-producer`

Comment: This is an example. I need to sink messages from a topic I don't own. How can I use the JSON converter for such messages?

Comment: The issue is that the current filter SMT requires a message schema. If data is pushed to the topic as a string, then it doesn't adhere to that contract, and you'd get an error similar to this - https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/#json-message-without-expected-schema-payload-structure So, my suggestion therefore is if you want to filter JSON data, then add KStreams/KSQL before you deploy your sink

Comment: There is a schemaless option as well. So if I change my config to 
"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false"
I get the error like "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonEOFException: Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: (byte[])"{"venue":{"venue_name":"Darius Wells Library and Resource Centre","lon":115.81395,"lat":-32"; line: 1, column: 10])"

Comment: Not sure about that error, but I'm talking about the SMT. Without a schema, you cannot know there is an acccessible "venue" field in the data.

Comment: there may be a way as Confluent seems to support something like this, but it is not free, so not tested: https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/connect/transforms/filter.html